# Get Terms by IDs with IDs order

Tags: query, terms

I want to get Terms by IDs with IDs order. But that doesn't working, WP automatically change the order.

My code-

```
$catsArray = array(159, 155, 143, 153, ......);
$series = get_terms( array(
              'taxonomy' => 'ctc_sermon_series',
              'number'  =>  9,
              'offset'  =>  $offset,
              'include' => $catsArray,
              'hide_empty'  => false, 
            ) );
```

And result-

```
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 155
            [name] => 10
            [slug] => 10
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 155
            [taxonomy] => ctc_sermon_series
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 159
            [name] => 14
            [slug] => 14
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 159
            [taxonomy] => ctc_sermon_series
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [2] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 153
            [name] => Name 8
            [slug] => name-8
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 153
            [taxonomy] => ctc_sermon_series
            [description] => Name 8 Des
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [3] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 143
            [name] => Series 1
            [slug] => series-1
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 143
            [taxonomy] => ctc_sermon_series
            [description] => Series 1 Description
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

I expect the result of term with ID-159 first, but every time i get result of ID-155 first. I need to get result by ID's array sequence.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I believe the question is how to get the terms back in the order of the Ids you've provided - which might not be sorted ascending or descending, but a random order instead.

Surprisingly, I think there's a shortcut for that in WP - who knew? This, I believe, is what you want to use:

```
$catsArray = array(159, 155, 143, 153, ......);
$series = get_terms( array(
          'taxonomy' => 'ctc_sermon_series',
          'number'  =>  9,
          'offset'  =>  $offset,
          'include' => $catsArray,
          'hide_empty'  => false, 
          'orderby'  => 'include', // <--- 
        ) );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you thought i've not tested.

```
$catsArray = array(159, 155, 143, 153, ......);
$series = get_terms( array(
              'taxonomy' => 'ctc_sermon_series',
              'number'  =>  9,
              'offset'  =>  $offset,
              'include' => $catsArray,
              'hide_empty'  => false, 
              'orderby' => 'term_id',
              'order' => 'DESC', // or ASC
            ) );
```

Comment: Actually i want to get terms by actual array order, not by term_id order.

Comment: got it. @MacPrawn answer is what you are looking for. upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Just use parametr 'fields'.

```
wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'some_taxonomy', array('fields' => 'ids'))
```

Read this https://wp-kama.com/function/wp_get_post_terms